# Git lfs repository to migration to non lfs repository failed

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-filter-repo

I have LFS repository, I need to take directories out to their own repository with no big files stored on git and with all commit history

I used the following flow

1. `git clone <LFS_REPO>`
2. Get all lfs files locally
   `git lfs fetch --all origin`
   `git lfs pull`
3. Remove the remote to protect the repo
   `git remote remove origin`
4. take directory with history
   `git filter-repo --path <LFS_DIR_IN_REPO>/ --force`
5. list all lfs files
   `git lfs ls-files --all > LFS_FILES.txt`
6. take lfs files as non-lfs (all files are less than 50 MB)
   `git lfs migrate export --everything --include .`
7. `git lfs uninstall`

after run all this, `.git/lfs/objects` folder contains files and I can't push the repository as non lfs.

What do I miss?

Comment: I was successfully removed the LFS to non LFS using your way.